# for loop to produce multiple polyfit scatter plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with 20 columns. I am looking to create scatter plots each with a line of best fit. The x column will be constant and I want to use a for loop to run through each of the other columns in the dataframe. The result would be 19 scatter plots.

my current setup looks something like this:

```
columns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7...20]
for column in columns:
    x= df[another column from the dataframe]
    y= df[column]
    fit = polyfit(x,y,1)
    fitx = poly1d(fit)
    plt.plot(x,y,'b+', 
             x,fitx(x),'b-')
```

This plots 19 best fit lines on a single axis rather than creates 19 axes. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create each of the subplots explicitly. In this toy code, I use a 4x5 grid which leads to an empty last plot.

The subplots are created with `plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, ...)`. My choice for 4x5 was arbitrary. You can easily adapt the grid by changing the number of rows and columns.

```
from itertools import chain

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
np.random.seed(42)

# prepare sample data
columns = ["col" + str(i) for i in range(1, 21)]
data = {col: np.random.rand(10) for col in columns}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


x_column = "col1"
cols = columns[:]
cols.remove(x_column)

plt, axes = plt.subplots(4, 5, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12,12))
flat_axes = chain(*axes)

for y_column, ax in zip(cols, flat_axes):
    if y_column != x_column:
        x = df[x_column]
        y = df[y_column]
        fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
        fitx = np.poly1d(fit)
        ax.plot(x, y, 'b+', x, fitx(x),'b-')
```

This is the result:
[image: plot]