# Use for loop for multi row column plot

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, scatter-plot

I am attempting to run a `for loop` in order to plot multiple scatter plots.  For the code that I have, I only get one plot at the end.  How to go about generating the correct `row` x `column` plots to save?

I have checked out some of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488885/for-loop-to-produce-multiple-polyfit-scatter-plots) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/84840/how-to-create-multiple-subplots-scatterplot-in-for-loop), but it does not work for me.  Is there a more optimum way to generate these plots?

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Generate noisy Data
num_trainsamples = 500
num_testsamples = 50
X_train,y_train = make_classification(n_samples=num_trainsamples, 
                          n_features=240, 
                          n_informative=9, 
                          n_redundant=0, 
                          n_repeated=0, 
                          n_classes=10, 
                          n_clusters_per_class=1,
                          class_sep=9,
                          flip_y=0.2,
                          #weights=[0.5,0.5], 
                          random_state=17)

n_components=2
n_neighbours=[1, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 30]
local_connectivity=2
min_dist=0.15
target_names = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8', 't9', 't10']

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

for i in range(0, len(n_neighbours)):
   
    plt.subplot(3,5,i+1)
    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(
        X_train[:, 0],
        X_train[:, 1],
        s = 20,
        c=y_train,
        cmap=plt.cm.nipy_spectral,
        edgecolor="k",
        linewidths=0.75,
        label=y_train,
        alpha=0.45,
    )
    plt.title(f'n_components = {n_components}, n_neighbors = {n_neighbours[i]}, local_conn = {local_connectivity}, min_dist = {min_dist}')
    cbar = plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.arange(11)-0.5)
    cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(10))
    cbar.set_ticklabels(target_names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for you seeing just one plot is the line `plt.clf()`. This command tells matplotlib to clear current figure. So, each time you loop through the code, it clear the previous figure and so, you see just the last one. Commenting that  line will give you the below figure, which is what I think you are looking for...

**PLOT**

[image]